# Unable to make push notifications works on a SwiftUI app with Firebase cloud Messaging

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I'm trying to implement push notifications with Firebase Cloud Messaging on an iOS application.

My applications uses the SwiftUI life cycle.

I followed the official documentation from Firebase  [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client)
But, for the moment, I'm unable to make it  works. I'try a lot of things, but none of them make the job. There is somebody who sees what can be the problem?

I tested on a real device, which ask me for the notification's permission. But no one arrives...

My AppDelegate class:

```
import SwiftUI
import FirebaseCore
import GoogleMobileAds
import FirebaseMessaging

class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {

func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                 didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        
        let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
            options: authOptions,
            completionHandler: { _, _ in }
        )
    } else {
        let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
        UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    }
    
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    
    Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
    
    GADMobileAds.sharedInstance().start(completionHandler: nil)
    return true
}
```

}

```
extension AppDelegate: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate{
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo
    
    Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
    
    // Change this to your preferred presentation option
    completionHandler([[.alert, .sound]])
}

func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
    
    Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
    
    completionHandler()
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                 didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any],
                 fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
    completionHandler(.noData)
}

func application(application: UIApplication,
                 didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken
}
```

}

```
extension AppDelegate: MessagingDelegate{
func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String?) {
    print("Firebase registration token: \(String(describing: fcmToken))")
    
    let dataDict: [String: String] = ["token": fcmToken ?? ""]
    NotificationCenter.default.post(
        name: Notification.Name("FCMToken"),
        object: nil,
        userInfo: dataDict
    )
    // TODO: If necessary send token to application server.
    // Note: This callback is fired at each app startup and whenever a new token is generated.
}
```

}

```
@main
struct BochoGameApp: App {
   @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var delegate
   var body: some Scene {
      WindowGroup {
        SplashScreen()
      }
   }
}
```

I created a key on my Apple account with the Apple Push Notifications service (APNs) service enabled. After I configured the Firebase console with it.
[image]
(I erased the empty fields for the image)

I set the next capabilities
[image]

On the info.pils I set FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled to false

Also, I have an App ID with the Push Notification checked
[image]

In my profile says I enable to use Push notifications.

[image]

And I set the provisioning profile on Xcode

Any idea? Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Okay, now I realize that with the methods of this post works also. You only have to edit that.

```
 completionHandler([[.banner,.badge ,.sound]]).
```